# TextView doesn't show in custom ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, android-custom-view

I try to create  custom `ScrollView`, which will have attribute `max_height`, but i faced with problem. When I set custom `height`, `ScrollView` doesn't show `TextView`.
 
Lite version of my code:
**Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.scrollviewtest.ExpandScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#Fe6" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView" />
</com.example.scrollviewtest.ExpandScrollView>
```

**ExpandScrollView.java**

```
public class ExpandScrollView extends ScrollView {

public ExpandScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, 180);

}}
```

So what do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved!
I just added `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);` before `widthSize`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the onMeasure() method in ExpandScrollView class. It is causing problem.
Once you remove it textview will be visible.

Comment: I extend `ScrollView` and `OnMeasure()` will have some logic, which changes `height`